# Regularity of heat equation with inhomogeneous Dirichlet boundary

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

Does anyone know a reference for the regularity theory of the Heat equation with inhomogeneous Dirichlet boundary condition:
$$\begin{cases} u_t(t,y) = u_{yy} (t,y) & (t,y)\in [0,T]\times \mathbb{R}_+\\ 
u(t,0)=h(t) & t \in [0,T]\\ 
u(0,y)=0 & y \in \mathbb{R}_+,
 \end{cases}\qquad (\star) $$
where $h\in C([0,T])$, $h(0)=0$, and $u_0$ continuous and rapidly decaying at infinity.

Specifically, I'm looking (if it exists) for an estimate of the type
$$\sup_{t\in [0,T]}|\partial^k_y u(t,y)| \leq C_k\sup_{t\in [0,T]}|h(t)|\Phi(y),\qquad \forall k\in\mathbb{N},\qquad (\spadesuit)$$
where $\Phi$ is rapidly decaying in $y$ (think of the heat kernel or one of its spatial derivatives, for instance).

I know that a solution of  $(\star)$ is given by the convolution
$$u(t,y)=-2\int_0^t\partial_y K(\tau,y)h(t-\tau)\,\mathrm{d}\tau= \int_{0}^t\frac{y}{\sqrt{4\pi \tau^3}}e^{-\frac{y^2}{4\tau}}h(t-\tau)\,\mathrm{d}\tau, $$
where $K(\tau,y)$ is the standard heat kernel.  Since $y\mapsto K(\tau,y)$ is smooth for all $t,y>0$, the derivatives in ($\spadesuit$) exist for these values. But do they exist at $y=0$ (it seems this would depend on the fact that $h(0)=0$)? And, can we bound them uniformly in time?  I'm not sure how to manipulate the kernel to get what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The estimate doesn't work as stated because we need higher order derivatives of the boundary function $h$ in the right-hand side.

Since $\lim_{y\to 0}-2\partial_yK(\tau,y)=\delta_\tau$ as distributions in $[0,t]$, we have
$$\lim_{y\to 0}\partial^{2k}_yu(t,y)= \lim_{y\to 0}\partial_t^ku(t,0)=\lim_{y\to 0}\int_{0}^t-2\partial_y K(\tau,y)h^{(k)}(t-\tau)\,\mathrm{d}\tau=h^{(k)}(t).$$
Because $y\mapsto \partial_yK(\tau,y)$ is smooth and rapidly decaying, we deduce that there exists a rapidly decaying smooth function $\Phi_k$ such that
$$|\partial_y^{2k}u(t,y)|\leq |h^{(k)}(t)|\Phi_k(y),\qquad \forall t\in [0,T],y\geq 0.$$
For odd derivatives we can just interpolate using the inequality
$$\|\partial_y^{2k+1}u(t)\|_{L^{\infty}(y,\infty)}\leq C_k\left( \|u(t)\|_{L^{\infty}(y,\infty)}+\|\partial_y^{2k+2}u(t)\|_{L^{\infty}(y,\infty)}\right), \quad \forall y \geq 0,$$
where $C_k$ is independent from $t$ and $y$. Hence we deduce
$$|\partial_y^ku(t,y)| \leq \left(\left|h^{(\left\lceil k/2\right\rceil)}(t)\right|+\left|h(t)\right|\right)\Phi_k(y),\qquad \forall k\in \mathbb{N},t\in [0,T],y\geq 0.$$

I believe, this is the correct version of the estimate.